# Special Table with Diagonal lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, rotating

Recently, I have to work with some problems that require to draw table like below in LaTeX. I used to think about diagonal line inside a cell, but it's not a good choice for this problem since the texts are not in diagonal direction.
Does anyone create something like this in LaTeX, can you suggest me any solution

[image: sample table]

Comment: Add your code (a minimal working example), it may be helpful and incite us to help.

Comment: Not only do you have the diagonal lines, there seems to be no relationship between the column widths and the contents.  For a one-off, you could probably reproduce it using Tikz.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:** See improved version in an [own answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/156555).

---

Here is a MWE of such a table.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newlength{\csize}
\newlength{\cwidth}
\newlength{\clabel}

\newcommand{\cell}[1]% centers text in cell
{node[above right,minimum width=\csize, minimum height=\csize]{#1}}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\csize}{1.5\baselineskip}% cell size (note: \baselineskip depends on current font)
\settowidth{\clabel}{simple label}% label width
\addtolength{\clabel}{1em}
\setlength{\cwidth}{2\csize}% total width (2 cells)
\addtolength{\cwidth}{\clabel}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (0,0) node[above right,fill=yellow,minimum width=\cwidth, minimum height=\csize]{};
\draw% horizontal lines
 (0,0) -- (\cwidth,0)
 (0,\csize) -- (\cwidth,\csize)
 (0,2\csize) -- (\cwidth,2\csize);
\path% labels
 (0,0) node[above right]{left}
 (\clabel,0) node[above left]{right}
 (0,\csize) node[above right]{simple label};

\begin{scope}[xshift=\clabel]
\draw% vertical lines
 (0,0) -- (0,2\csize)
 (\csize,0) -- (\csize,2\csize)
 (2\csize,0) -- (2\csize,2\csize);
\path% fill cells
 (0,\csize) \cell{1}
 (\csize,\csize) \cell{2}
 (0,0) \cell{3}
 (\csize,0) \cell{4};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=\clabel, yshift=2\csize]
\draw% diagonal lines
 (0,0) -- ++(45:\clabel)
 (\csize,0) -- ++(45:\clabel)
 (2\csize,0) -- ++(45:\clabel);
\path% diagonal labels
 (\csize,0) node[above right,rotate=45]{first}
 (2\csize,0) node[above right,rotate=45]{second};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: table]

Comment: I tried using a \matrix, but the lines didn't quite match.

Comment: BTW, I have an improved version now.  Should I replace the above?

Comment: Nobody noticed until now. Clear answer: Yes! If the change is big, then add the new code below the other and point to this better version before the older version.

Comment: I'll see if I still have it.  The idea was to put the origin in a common location (upper left corner of 1),

Answer (score 12):

Reproduction of the table without `tikz`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{pifont}

\begin{document}
  \begingroup
    \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.5}%
    \definecolor{tabred}{RGB}{230,36,0}%
    \definecolor{tabgreen}{RGB}{0,116,21}%
    \definecolor{taborange}{RGB}{255,124,0}%
    \definecolor{tabbrown}{RGB}{171,70,0}%
    \definecolor{tabyellow}{RGB}{255,253,169}%
    \newcommand*{\redtriangle}{\textcolor{tabred}{\ding{115}}}%
    \newcommand*{\greenbullet}{\textcolor{tabgreen}{\ding{108}}}%
    \newcommand*{\orangecirc}{\textcolor{taborange}{\ding{109}}}%
    \newcommand*{\headformat}[1]{{\small#1}}%
    \newcommand*{\vcorr}{%
      \vadjust{\vspace{-\dp\csname @arstrutbox\endcsname}}%
      \global\let\vcorr\relax
    }%
    \newcommand*{\HeadAux}[1]{%
      \multicolumn{1}{@{}r@{}}{%
        \vcorr
        \sbox0{\headformat{\strut #1}}%
        \sbox2{\headformat{Complex Data Movement}}%
        \sbox4{\kern\tabcolsep\redtriangle\kern\tabcolsep}%
        \sbox6{\rotatebox{45}{\rule{0pt}{\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0\relax}}}%
        \sbox0{\raisebox{.5\dimexpr\dp0-\ht0\relax}[0pt][0pt]{\unhcopy0}}%
        \kern.75\wd4 %
        \rlap{%
          \raisebox{.25\wd4}{\rotatebox{45}{\unhcopy0}}%
        }%
        \kern.25\wd4 %
        \ifx\HeadLine Y%
          \dimen0=\dimexpr\wd2+.5\wd4\relax
          \rlap{\rotatebox{45}{\hbox{\vrule width\dimen0 height .4pt}}}%
        \fi
      }%
    }%
    \newcommand*{\head}[1]{\HeadAux{\global\let\HeadLine=Y#1}}%
    \newcommand*{\headNoLine}[1]{\HeadAux{\global\let\HeadLine=N#1}}%
    \noindent
    \begin{tabular}{%
      >{\bfseries}lc|>{\quad}c
      *{4}{c|}c>{\quad}c
      *{4}{c|}c>{\quad}c
      *{2}{c|}c%
    }%
      &
      \head{Data Dimensions} &
      &
      \head{Single Input/Output} &
      \head{Statc Rates} &
      \head{Hierachical Memory} &
      \head{Complex Data Movement} &
      \headNoLine{Single Kernel Execution} &
      &
      \head{Application graph} &
      \head{Implicit memory access} &
      \head{Theoretical Framework} &
      \head{Out-of-band control} &
      \headNoLine{Real-time constraints} &
      &
      \head{Data Parallelism} &
      \head{Pipeline Parallelism} &
      \headNoLine{Task Parallelism}
      \\
      \sbox0{S}%
      \rule{0pt}{\dimexpr\ht0 + 2ex\relax}%
      StreamIt & \textcolor{tabred}{\bfseries 1} &&
      \redtriangle & \redtriangle & & & &&
      \greenbullet & \greenbullet & \orangecirc & \greenbullet & &&
      \greenbullet & \greenbullet & \greenbullet
      \\\hline
      StreamC/KernelC & \textcolor{tabred}{\bfseries 1} &&
      & & & & \redtriangle &&
      \greenbullet & \greenbullet & & \greenbullet & &&
      \greenbullet & &
      \\\hline
      SDF & \textcolor{tabred}{\bfseries 1} &&
      & \redtriangle & & & &&
      \greenbullet & \greenbullet & \greenbullet & & &&
      & \greenbullet & \greenbullet
      \\\hline
      MDSDF & \textcolor{tabgreen}{\bfseries\itshape n} &&
      & \redtriangle & & \redtriangle & &&
      \greenbullet & \greenbullet & \greenbullet & & &&
      \greenbullet & \greenbullet & \greenbullet
      \\\hline
      ArrayOL & \textcolor{tabgreen}{\bfseries\itshape n} &&
      & \redtriangle & & \redtriangle & &&
      \greenbullet & \greenbullet & \orangecirc & & &&
      \greenbullet & \greenbullet & \greenbullet
      \\\hline
      Brook & \textcolor{tabgreen}{\bfseries\itshape n} &&
      & & & & \redtriangle &&
      & \greenbullet & & & &&
      \greenbullet & &
      \\\hline
      Sequoia & \textcolor{tabgreen}{\bfseries\itshape n} &&
      & & \redtriangle & \redtriangle & \redtriangle &&
      & & & & &&
      \greenbullet & &
      \\\hline
      \rowcolor{tabyellow}%
      Block-parallel & \textcolor{tabbrown}{\bfseries 2} &&
      & \redtriangle & & & &&
      \greenbullet & \greenbullet & \orangecirc & \greenbullet &
        \greenbullet &&
      \greenbullet & \greenbullet & \greenbullet
      \\[.5ex]
      \multicolumn{3}{c}{} &
      \multicolumn{5}{c}{\bfseries Limitations} &&
      \multicolumn{5}{c}{\bfseries Features} &&
      \multicolumn{3}{c}{\bfseries Parallelism}
      \\
    \end{tabular}%
    \kern19.5mm % manually with the help of the next \vrule
    % \vrule height 50mm
  \endgroup
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Remarks:**

- The color values are taken from the image.
- The symbols come from the symbol font Zapf Dingbats. `\ding` of package `pifont` access these symbols.
- The background color of the last table line is done by `\rowcolor` of package `colortbl`.
- The rotation is done with `\rotatebox` of the `graphics` (`graphicx`) package.
- The depth of the head line row is empty, therefore the vertical line would be missing. This is fixed by moving the head line down with `\vcorr` until the rotated lines hits the vertical column lines.
- The value of the `\kern` after the end of the table is set manually with the help of the following rule. The white space by `\kern` notifies LaTeX that the table is larger than it thinks because of the overlap of the rotated headers.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the improved version (common scope).

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

% create symbols

\newcommand{\reddot}{\tikz{\fill[red] (0,0) circle (4pt);}}
\newcommand{\greentriangle}{\tikz{\fill[green] (0,0) -- (4.62pt,8pt) -- (9.23pt,0) -- cycle;}}
\newcommand{\bigx}{\tikz{\draw[black,thick] (0,0) -- (7pt,7pt) (0,7pt) -- (7pt,0);}}

\newlength{\csize}
\newlength{\clabel}
\newlength{\cwidth}

\newcommand{\cell}[1]% centers text in cell
{node[above right,minimum width=\csize, minimum height=\csize]{#1}}

\begin{document}

test \reddot \greentriangle \bigx \checkmark $\bigstar$

\setlength{\csize}{1.5\baselineskip}% cell size (note: \baselineskip depends on current font)
\addtolength{\csize}{.6666em}
\settowidth{\clabel}{longest label}% label width
\addtolength{\clabel}{.6666em}
\setlength{\cwidth}{2\csize}% total width
\addtolength{\cwidth}{\clabel}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (-\clabel,-2\csize) node[above right,fill=yellow,minimum width=\cwidth, minimum height=\csize]{};
\draw% horizontal lines
 (-\clabel,0) -- (2\csize,0)
 (-\clabel,-\csize) -- (2\csize,-\csize)
 (-\clabel,-2\csize) -- (2\csize,-2\csize);
\path% labels
 (-\clabel,-2\csize) node[above right]{left}
 (0,-2\csize) node[above left]{right}
 (-0.5\clabel,-\csize) node[above]{center};
\draw% vertical lines
 (0,0) -- (0,-2\csize)
 (\csize,0) -- (\csize,-2\csize)
 (2\csize,0) -- (2\csize,-2\csize);
\path% fill cells
 (0,-\csize) \cell{1}
 (\csize,-\csize) \cell{2}
 (0,-2\csize) \cell{3}
 (\csize,-2\csize) \cell{4};
\draw% diagonal lines
 (0,0) -- ++(45:\clabel)
 (\csize,0) -- ++(45:\clabel)
 (2\csize,0) -- ++(45:\clabel);
\path% diagonal labels
 (\csize,0) node[above right,rotate=45]{first}
 (2\csize,0) node[above right,rotate=45]{second};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: table]

Comment: Just as remark: [Why should the minimal class be avoided?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42114).

Comment: A lot of standard latex features are not defined.  Back when I wrote this, I was planning to replace article with minimal on everything, but I started getting odd errors so I went back to article.

Comment: Nope, I see clearly `\documentclass{minimal}`, BTW already in the older version.

Comment: They were both written at the same time (more or less).