# Beautiful tables with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

Tables generated by LaTeX are usually not good looking. The standard thickness of row and column separators and also the corners where the rules meet leave much to be desired. Are there any examples of beautiful tables using TikZ available?

Comment: I don't agree with the first line. Search in this site for pretty tables.

Comment: This question has been asked before; search for something like beautiful table examples.  Many people (here) will also tell you that the best thickness of column separators is `0pt`, and that unobtrusive tables are more aesthetically appealing that 'beautiful' ones...

Comment: Read the documentation for `booktabs`...

Comment: Not in the list: "http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149942/special-table-with-diagonal-lines/156555#156555

Comment: For instance, give a try to the [`tabu`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabu) package.

Comment: @Malipivo -- be careful with `tabu`; the author is (still) working on a new release and backwards compatibility is not a priority.  There's a thread on `comp.text.tex` where it is discussed.

Comment: @jon http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3859/dangerous-packages-what-can-we-do-about-them-on-tex-sx

Comment: @percusse -- Oh, yeah.  I forgot about that!